# Multiple generic class inheritance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, inheritance

Consider I have one model and a base model for it:

```
class BaseModel: NSObject {
    var name = ""
}

class Model: BaseModel {
    var desc = "abc"
}
```

I added a services to work with those models:

```
class AbstractService<T: NSObject>: NSObject {
    var items = [T]()
}

class BaseModelService<T: BaseModel>: AbstractService<BaseModel> {
}

class ModelService<T: Model>: BaseModelService<Model> {
}
```

Now I want to access `items` variable from `ModelService` and expect to get an array of `Model`s, but I get `BaseModel`s instead:

[image: Error message: Cannot assign a value of type [BaseModel] to a value of type [Model]]

Did I miss something with generics?

Here is a full code for Playground:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

/// Models:
class BaseModel: NSObject {
    var name = ""
}

class Model: BaseModel {
    var desc = "abc"
}

/// Services:
class AbstractService<T: NSObject>: NSObject {
    var items = [T]()
}

class BaseModelService<T: BaseModel>: AbstractService<BaseModel> {
}

class ModelService<T: Model>: BaseModelService<Model> {
}

/// ViewController:
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let modelService = ModelService()
    var items = [Model]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        items = modelService.items // The error appears here: Cannot assign a value of type [BaseModel] to a value of type [Model]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the declarations should be:

```
class BaseModelService<T: BaseModel>: AbstractService<T> {
}

class ModelService: BaseModelService<Model> {
}
```

When you do:

```
class BaseModelService<T: BaseModel>: AbstractService<BaseModel> {
}
```

`T` for `AbstractService` and `T` for `BaseModelService` are two distinct types.
The former constrained to concrete `BaseModel`, whereas the latter is constrained to subtype of `BaseModel`, and not used at all.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you force `BaseModelService` to be a subclass of `AbstractModelService<BaseModel>` which means that `items` is typed `[BaseModel]`.  Declare `BaseModelService` as follows:

```
class BaseModelService<T: BaseModel>: AbstractService<T> {
```

Then you are good to go.